# What do you call a series of words connected by hyphens?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am doing an English Language AS Level past paper and in it is written "They all pop up in the film in a when-brands-collide whirlwind" and later on "Emmet is mistakenly drafted into a save-the-world mission".

What do you call a series of words ("when-brands-collide" and "save-the-world"), rather than just two, that are connected by hyphens?

Written in another part of the paper is "Thanks to the host of iconic characters, and unique cross-generational appeal, the bricks may be...".  I believe "cross-generational" is a compound adjective.  Am I right?

Comment: Compound words.

Comment: Yes, the hyphens hold words (not necessarily adjectives) together to form a single adjectivial phrase.

Comment: I assume you mean adjectival.  Which, I assume you to mean of or like an adjective.  Fleur-de-lis is not an adjective.

Comment: In your case, *Hyphenated compound words*.

Comment: They are compound words. Your examples are typical nonce-forms, concocted on-the-hoof, rather than well-established forms, and treated as single compound words. Restricted to attributive modifier function, they are best treated as compound adjectives. "Cross-generational", though, is fairly well-established, but again is treated as a compound adjective.

Comment: there has got to be something else to call this.. as I don't think the purpose is to form a new word but to emphasis that the words be understood in an idiomatic way. 'he-who-shall-not-be-named' or "oh-so-clever" are others examples...  coined expressions? I don't know

Comment: I believe that usually phrases treated in such way are neologisms however it isn't the hyphens qualifying them as such ...

Comment: I'd like to echo @Tom22 with my hope that there is a better term. Yes, they are multi-hyphenated-compound-words, but so is that right there, and the function is different. In the examples the hyphens allow verbed-phrases, which would otherwise confuse the reader, to read as adjectives. The hyphens, in a sense, neuter the verb function and tell the reader to read it as a phrase.

Comment: @Unrelated They are compound words functioning as modifiers in NP structure. They don't conform to the normal structure of compounds and it's difficult to draw a clear line between syntax and morphology with such words - hence they must be regarded as adjectives irrespective of the individual bases. You could call them "dephrasal compounds". As I said before, many of these expressions are simply concocted on the hoof, which is why I called them nonce-formations

Comment: @BillJ I did appreciate your nonce-formations

Comment: The appropriate term in linguistics is "constituent".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "hyphenated adjectives", as *a)* both your examples are adjectives; and *b)* correct me if I'm wrong, but most of these hyphenated compound words take the form of adjectives.

There is a great set of examples [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_adjectives.htm).

Answer (score -3):

Tmesis - the separation of parts of a compound word by an intervening word or words, used mainly in informal speech for emphasis (e.g. can't find it any-blooming-where ).

A great word for a great bit o' grammar.

Comment: Great word … but not the correct answer to this question. None of the asker's examples are tmesis.