# Is this phrase "The red jacket wearing guy" correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I am about to say this to my friend:

> The guy who is wearing the red jacket is so handsome.

But I ended up saying like this:

> <s>The red jacket wearing guy is so handsome.</s>
>
> **The red-jacket-wearing guy is so handsome.**

Is the latter grammatically correct? And if so, what is the grammar point here?

Thanks in advance!

## Update:

- Fix punctuation

Comment: _The guy wearing the red jacket is very handsome._ is idiomatic.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381796/what-do-you-call-a-series-of-words-connected-by-hyphens

Comment: It's so simple that makes my question looks dull. Thanks a lot! @Unrelated

Comment: It's grammatical, but badly punctuated. There should be a hyphen in _jacket-wearing_; in fact, some style guides insist that, since it's not just a compound of [jacket] + [wearing], but of [red jacket] + [wearing], it ought to be an en dash: _red jacket–wearing_, to make it clear that it's a guy wearing a red jacket, not a red guy wearing a jacket. With no hyphen at all, you would expect it to mean “the red jacket which is wearing guy”, if that weren't so nonsensical.

Comment: "The guy wearing the red jacket" focuses on a guy, and wearing the red jacket identifies him.  "The red jacket wearing guy" sounds like red jacket wearing is some standard identifying trait, like the trademark attire for some organization, and the guy is a member.